Knowing that the area of the shaded region is 2π, find the length of the chord PQ
Diagram
The diagram shows two circles contained within a larger circle. The shaded region is the area of the larger circle minus the area of the the two enclosed circles. A chord PQ is tangent to both of the enclosed circles.
I would greatly appreciate some help since I haven't gone anywhere with the question. I know the area of the shaded region is the area of the large circle subtracted by the area of the two smaller circles, but I don't know how I'm supposed to find a numerical value for the areas of any shapes here.

Draw the diameter of the biggest circle through center of small circles and the triangle with diameter and point $P$. Then $\angle P=90^{\circ}$ and diam$\perp PQ$
Let radii of small circles $R$ and $r$ then radius of the biggest one is $R+r$.
Area $=(R+r)^2\pi-R^2\pi-r^2\pi=2\pi$
$R\times r=1$
$(\frac{PQ}{2})^2=2R\times 2r$ (Euclidean Theorem in a right $\triangle$)
$PQ=$ you can get it.
